# Retrieve contacts based on a list of external IDs

Tags: data-loader, data-export

I have a csv with 126,000 External Ids for contacts coming from another system.

I need to export all of the contacts from salesforce where the id is in the CSV.

I was thinking of doing an update with the External Ids from the CSV to check a box on the contact records and then simply export the records using that checkbox. Is there an efficient way of doing this without updating the records, I feel like I'm overthinking this?

Comment: Assuming the total number of contacts isn't large (YMMV), simply exporting all of them and doing the merge outside of SF might be easier.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and solved it by:

- Uploaded the CSV to a Document (or you could use a File)
- Wrote a batch job
- Constructor accepted the DeveloperName of the Document
- `start()` method queried the Document, and used a CSV Parser to return an iterable
- `execute()` method that built up a CSV using Database.stateful; flushing the CSV to a File when Heap was close to breaching
- `finish()` that sent an email with a link to a URL that downloaded a zip of the CSV File(s)
- Attached this all to a button in the Utility Bar tha was a screen flow + invocable apex (that started the batch job)

I did this because the export task would be run many times with different inputs and the number of fields in the exported CSV was small

Worked for about 350,000 external Ids before running out of heap in `start()`. YMMV.